# Trying to rename a columns of a table in laravel throws error

Tags: php, laravel

I follow the [guide here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#modifying-columns) in modifying the column in Laravel.

I have table `stores` 
and run this in command line

`php artisan make:migration rename_stores_column --table="stores" --create`

After creating the migration

here the code

```
class RenameStoresColumn extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('stores', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->renameColumn('store_iamge', 'store_image');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('stores', function (Blueprint $table) {
          $table->renameColumn('store_image', 'store_iamge');
        });
    }
}
```

but when i run `php artisan migrate`

I got this error,

```
In Connection.php line 664:

  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'stores' already exists (SQL: create table `stores` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `name` varchar(255) null, `address` varchar(255) null, `city` varchar(255) null, `zipcode` varc
  har(255) null, `country` varchar(255) null, `state` varchar(255) null, `latitude` double(10, 6) not null, `longitude` double(10, 6) not null, `description` text null, `phone` varchar(255) null, `email` varchar(255) null, `fax` varchar(255) null, `web` varchar(255) n
  ull, `tags` varchar(255) null, `schedule` varchar(255) null, `store_iamge` varchar(255) null, `marker_image` varchar(255) null, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)


In PDOStatement.php line 143:

  SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'stores' already exists
```

what the proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem that your issue has anything to do with this `rename_stores_column` migration. It looks like `php artisan migrate` tries to rerun the `create_stores_table` migration even though it was already run.

Now you may come across this issue easily if at any point you have an error in one of your migrations, because the migration runs, it creates the table, but then the error occurs, the batch fails and it doesn't manage to insert the name of the migration in `migrations` table, so at the next migrate it will run it again, thus the issue you have here.

To solve this, you either run a fresh migrate (`php artisan migrate:fresh`) but **only if you are on a dev environment and don't have any data to lose**.

Or, in `create_stores_table` migration wrap the `schema create` in a `schema has`, so even if it tries to run it, if the table already exists it won't do anything:

```
if (!Schema::hasTable('stores')) {
  Schema::create('stores', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');

    ...
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, it works, php artisan migrate:fresh no worries.. i'm in dev environment

Answer (score 3):

Did you require `doctrine/dbal`?

> **Prerequisites**
>
> Before modifying a column, be sure to add the doctrine/dbal dependency to your  composer.json file. The Doctrine DBAL library is used to determine the current state of the column and create the SQL queries needed to make the specified adjustments to the column:

```
composer require doctrine/dbal
```

Comment: The other option is that there are multiple migrations which try to create (`Schema::create`) the stores` table. Could you verify this?